# Why dose the my service class's createPerson() return null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I can't find the problem.
Here are my classes:

Test class :
[image]

PersonService :

[image]

PersonRepository:
[image]

Comment: Maybe your code also has obvious spelling mistakes?

Comment: Where? do you mean in test class?

Comment: What about test class definition? Mocks, spies ?

Comment: yes, I use Mocks

Comment: And without pre-configurations like `when(mock...).thenReturn(...)` you are always going to receive null values when interacting with mocks. Your problem is with a test class, so it would be helpful if you could expand it.

Comment: i have expanded it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @RezaHosseini since in testcase you are using mock it doesnt call the actual method. You need to provide the return value using when(mock.creatPerson()).thenReturn(predfinedPersonObject) to be able to you the value. Maybe some reading around how we use mocks will be helpful.

Comment: I had before this code in test  : when(personRepository.save(any())).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
but this returns me an empty array